# Unity ui and coroutines

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to modify a unity code for a game.

I need that at a certain point, the module stops, while the rest of the UI continues.
I've tried with System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(8000); but it blocks the whole code

this is the part im trying to mod

```cs
void OnTimerExpired()
    {

        Module.OnStrike();
        Debug.LogFormat("[NeedyQRCode #{0}] Timed out! Strike!", _moduleId);
        QR.enabled = false;
        _isReady = false;

    }
```

With coroutines, this is the result.

```cs
void OnTimerExpired()
    {
        StartCoroutine(NextScene());
    }
    IEnumerator NextScene() 
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (5.0f);
        Module.OnStrike();
        Debug.LogFormat("[NeedyQRCode #{0}] Timed out! Strike!", _moduleId);
        QR.enabled = false;
        _isReady = false;
    }
```

I am getting this result in the compiler  System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator requires 1 type argument. How can I correct the code?

Comment: There is no question in this post. You simply  said *"I'm trying to modify a unity code for a game."* with bunch of codes. Please edit your post and as a question. If you get an error, post the error in the question and tell us where the error is happening.

Comment: @Joseph, edit the question with the error instead of just commenting on it.

Comment: yeah, sorry, couldn't find the edit button